# How to delete existing records and add new datas in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, database, core-data

Following is my code to add records to core data db....
pendingShipmentDAO is a NSObjectModel. The problem  is that, each time when a button is clicked new data is being embedded. How can I clear all records in data in the db, if there are datas already present in my db and insert new datas?

```
if((self.pendingShipmentDAO) )
{
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"shipmentno"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:proformaInvoiceNumber forKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:proformaInvoiceDate forKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:invoiceNo forKey:@"invoice_no"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:invoiceDate forKey:@"invoice_date"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:plannedShipmentDates forKey:@"planned_shipment_date"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:address forKey:@"point_of_contact"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:address forKey:@"empid"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:name forKey:@"products"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:qty forKey:@"quantity"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:rte forKey:@"rate"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:amt forKey:@"amount"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:img forKey:@"product_image"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:pendingStatus forKey:@"status"];
}
else
{
    NSManagedObject *pendingShipment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [pendingShipment setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"shipmentno"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:proformaInvoiceNumber forKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:proformaInvoiceDate forKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:invoiceNo forKey:@"invoice_no"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:invoiceDate forKey:@"invoice_date"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:plannedShipmentDates forKey:@"planned_shipment_date"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:address forKey:@"point_of_contact"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:address forKey:@"empid"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:name forKey:@"products"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:qty forKey:@"quantity"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:rte forKey:@"rate"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:amt forKey:@"amount"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:img forKey:@"product_image"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:pendingStatus forKey:@"status"];
}
```

UPDATE:

This is how Im fetching datas,

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"PendingShipmentDetails"];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (result.count > 0) {
        int i;
        amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        statusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        shipmentReferenceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        invoiceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (i = 0; i < [result count]; i++) {
            //NSLog(@"%@", result);
            pending = (NSManagedObject *)[result objectAtIndex:i];
                        NSLog(@"pro inv no %@",[pending valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"]);
                        NSLog(@"shipment no %@",[pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"]);
                        NSLog(@"pro inv date %@",[pending valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"]);
                        NSLog(@"inv no %@",[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_no"]);
                        NSLog(@"inv date %@",[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_date"]);
                        NSLog(@"pl sh date %@",[pending valueForKey:@"planned_shipment_date"]);
                        NSLog(@"pt ct %@",[pending valueForKey:@"point_of_contact"]);
                        NSLog(@"pro %@",[pending valueForKey:@"products"]);
                        NSLog(@"qty %@",[pending valueForKey:@"quantity"]);
                        NSLog(@"rte %@",[pending valueForKey:@"rate"]);
                        NSLog(@"amt %@",[pending valueForKey:@"amount"]);
                        NSLog(@"pro imng %@", [pending valueForKey:@"product_image"]);
                        NSLog(@"statsus %@", [pending valueForKey:@"status"]);

            // amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[pending valueForKey:@"amount"], nil];
            [amountArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"amount"]];
            [statusArray addObject: [pending valueForKey:@"status"]];
            [shipmentReferenceNumberArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"]];
            [invoiceNumberArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_no"]];

        }

    }
```

Comment: are you want to delete all present rows or just one row with some matching ID ?

Comment: delete all rows and add new datas freshly

Answer (score 0):

Just Call this below method before adding new data in core data with your entity name.

```
-(void)deleteAllPreviousData {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Your Entity Name" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Could not delete Entity Objects");
    }
    for (NSManagedObject *currentObj in fetchedObjects) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:currentObj];
    }
    [context save:&error];
}
```

Comment: it deletes everything and even the newly inserted datas are getting deleted

Comment: yes, it removes all record. if you want to remove particular record than you have to use NSPredicate..

Comment: what i want is that it should delete existing record and add new records freshly

Answer (score 0):

Do things (delete, insert) synchronously in same managed object context.

1. you need to create a Managed Object Context (MOC) with one of the concurrent types: `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`or `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` depending on your needs.
2. use `performBlockAndWait:` to do things

   ```
   [context performBlockAndWait:^{

       // remove all rows    
       NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"PendingShipmentDetails"];
       NSError *error;
       NSArray * pendingShipments = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
       for (NSManagedObject *pendingShipment in pendingShipments) {
           [context deleteObject: pendingShipment];
       }

       // add new row(s)

       NSManagedObject *pendingShipment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];

       // TODO: set values here (e.g. [pendingShipment setValue:...)

       // save MOC
       if ([context hasChanges]) {
           (void)[context save:&error];
       }
   }];
   ```

**NOTE:** if you need to reference the MOC **inside the block**, use `context`.

See [Core Data Programming Guide: Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html) for details.

Comment: can you please elaborate with reference to my code?

Comment: thank you that works but while fetching , only lastly added elements are being fetched.

Comment: only the last value is being inserted and the rest of them are deleted in `performBlockAndWait`

Comment: fetch data the way code snipped does it in first 3 lines after `// remove all rows`

Comment: still the same error. and only one record record is being inserted

Comment: are you sure, you actually have inserted **more than one** record? what **same error** are you referring to?